# Showing product x is added as message [Modx]

Tags: php, modx-revolution, simplecart

With Magento you can see a message, "Productname" is added to the cart.

I need this message too!

I use SimpleCart package as Modx Revolution webshop. (not simplecart.js)

Really don't know how to do this.
I have a Snippet with this content which might be the right one where to add some code! 
http://pastebin.com/7A4Twhim

Does anyone knows howto?

(Below code didn't work)

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['addcart']) && $_POST['addcart']=='Add' ) {
    return '<div class="message">The product is added to the basket</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you need to add in your snippet before this line

```
$url = $modx->makeUrl($redirectTo, '', '', $redirectScheme);
```

this:

```
setcookie('added_prod', $productId, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/'); // set cookie
```

and then create snippet [[!product_added]]

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE) && isset($_COOKIE['added_prod']) && !empty($_COOKIE['added_prod'])) {
    $id_prod = (int) $_COOKIE['added_prod'];
    $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource',$id_prod);
    setcookie("added_prod", "", time()-3600); // unset cookie
    return '<div class="message">The product "'.$resource->get('pagetitle').'" is added to the basket</div>';
}
```

Comment: Hey Vasis, thanks allot man. It works :D
There is a new problem now :( it needs to disappear after going to a other page, so the cookie needs to be deleted somehow? Any thoughts?

I do see this line: setcookie("added_prod", "", time()-3600); // unset cookie but it doesn't disappear

Comment: ** It doesn't dissapear while it should be after 1 minute?

Comment: hope you can still help me out on this one, really appreciate you made the snippet for me!

Comment: `setcookie("added_prod", "", time()-3600, '/');` - may not work because I forgot `'/'`.